# How this recursive code works.I'm trying to understand the concept but couln't get throuh it

Tags: java, recursion

```
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int ar[] = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            ar[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        HelloWorld h = new HelloWorld();
        h.find(ar, a);
    }

    public void find(int ar[], int a) {
        System.out.println(a);
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
            if (ar[i] == a) {
                //System.out.println(a+" "+i);
                a = a + 1;
                find(ar, a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
2
1
2
1
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
3
```

Can anyone explains me how that recursive code generate the following output?

Comment: Use a debugger to to through the code, or even run through it with pencil and paper to write down the variable values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you input**

```
2
1
2
1
```

- n = the first number = 2
- ar = next n(2) numbers = [1,2]
- a = fourth
  number = 1

then the find method is called as:

```
h.find(ar = [1,2], a = 1);
```

**For the output:**
Inside find method

- **`a = 1` is printed.** As passed from the main method.
- `ar = [1,2]` is iterated.
- Since `a[0] = 1 = a`, a is incremented to 2. `find(ar = [1,2], a = 2)` is called.

  - **`a = 2` is printed.**
  - `ar = [1,2]` is iterated.
  - This time `a[0] = 1 != a = 2.`
  - Next element, `a[1] = 2 = a`, a is incremented to 3. `find(ar = [1,2], a = 3)` is called.

    - **`a = 3` is printed.**.
    - `ar = [1,2]` is iterated.
    - No element in ar is equal to `a = 3`.
- `a[1] = 2 = a`. *a was turned from 1 to 2 in prev iteration*. Again `a = 2+1=3`. `find(ar = [1,2], a = 3)` is called.

  - **`a = 3` is printed.**.
  - `ar = [1,2]` is iterated.
  - No element in ar is equal to a = 3.

Final Output:

```
1
2
3
3
```

**Point to note:**

If you change value of primitive type variables (like `int a`) inside a recursive call, the change will not affect value of a for the parent function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get confused about the recursive code - AFAIK it could be done without recursive code.

It looks like it sorts the content of the variable ar in a weard kind and removes duplicates.
But if the value does not exist in ar, it simply prints out a for each element of ar.
And if a exists in ar, it prints the next higher value,
and if that exists in ar, it prints the next higher value,
but if currernt value of a does not exist in ar, just print it for the remaining loop iterations.

```
a at start = 0
result = 0 0 0 0

a at start = 1
result = 1 2 3 3

a at start = 2
result = 2 3 3 3

a at start = -infinite ... 0, 3, 4, ... +infite
result = a a a a

if ar = 1 2 4 5 (order of elements does not matter)
a = 0, result = 0 0 0 0
a = 1, result = 1 2 3 3
a = 2, result = 2 3 3 3
a = 3, result = 3 3 3 3
a = 4, result = 4 5 6 6
a = 5, result = 5 6 6 6
a = 6, result = 6 6 6 6
```

PS: The recusivity is not really needed, too few parameters change, only a.

The content of find without recursivity

```
public void find(int ar[], int a) {        
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(a);

        if (doesArrayContain(ar, a)) {
            //System.out.println(a+" "+i)
            a = a + 1;
        }
    }
}

private boolean doesArrayContain(int ar[], int a) {
    for (int idx = 0; idx < ar.length; idx++) {
        if (ar[idx] == a) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it appears that you start with

looping an through an integer 'array of size n' to find a value 'a'
if it exists you are then recusing to find 'a+1'

```
main.find [1,2], 1
console >>    1
    first recursive [1,2], 2.      --------  match for 1
    consoles >> 2
        second recursive [1,2] 3.  --------  match for 2
        consoles >> 3
        exit second recursive (no match for 3)
    third recursive [1,2], 2.      --------  match for 2
    consoles >> 3
    exit third recursive (no match for 3)
loop ends
```